# NuxtJS - Prevent fetch if data already exists in state?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I have a portfolio site built using NuxtJS and a headless Wordpress CMS. On several pages, I'm importing a mixin that looks like this:

```
import { mapActions, mapState } from 'vuex';

export default {
  computed: {
    ...mapState({
      galleries: state => state.portfolio.galleries[0],
    })
  },

  methods: {
    ...mapActions('portfolio', ['fetchGalleries']),
  },

  async fetch() {
    await this.fetchGalleries();
  }
}
```

The Vuex module looks like this:

```
export const state = () => ({
  galleries: [],
});

export const actions = {
  async fetchGalleries({ commit }) {
    let res = await this.$axios.$get(`${process.env.WP_API_URL}/wp/v2/media`);
    const data = res.reduce((acc, item) => {
      const { slug } = item.acf.category;
      (acc[slug] || (acc[slug] = [])).push(item);
      return acc;
    }, {});

    commit('setGalleries', data);
  }
};

export const mutations = {
  setGalleries(state, data) {
    state.galleries.push(data);
  }
};
```

`fetch` is being used in the mixin to return data from the api before page load. I noticed however that each time I navigate to a new page, it's running that same `fetch` and continually adding duplicate data to Vuex state.

[image: vuex devtools]

How do I prevent `fetch` from running and continually adding duplicate data to my state if it already exists?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why this was tripping me up so much, but I figured out a very simple solution.

```
async fetch() {
  if (this.galleries.length) return;
  await this.fetchGalleries();
}
```

Just added a conditional return statement as the first line within the `fetch` function.